# How to know how many values you need to find for a trig equation

Tags: trigonometry

So when it comes to solving trig equations, I find it very easy. But when it asks you to find the values between the range of $0<x<360$ I get my value just add $180$ and take it away from $360$ but I understand that's not right. I got told you can tell how many values you find from the actual equation but I don't understand that. For example find the values of $$9 \cos^2x-\sin2x+4$$ between the range of $0 < x < 360$. How would I know how many values I need to find?

Comment: Yes, I wrote more but I don't know what's happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the unit circle as your guide. In any equation, just replace $\cos\theta$ with $x$ and  $\sin \theta$ with $y$, then draw the curve on the plane with the unit circle. When the curve and the unit circle intersect, that is a solution.

For example, $\sin \theta=1/2$ becomes $y=1/2$. So you draw a horizontal line at height $1/2$ on the unit circle, and you see it has 2 intersections, $\theta = \pi/6$ and $\theta=5\pi/6$. Those are all the solutions between $0$ and $2\pi%$ (you can convert everything to degrees and it's the same idea).

If you have a different range like $0$ to $4\pi$, you find out how many full circles there are (2 in this case), and multiply the number of solutions for one circle by the number of circles. For the example, there's two solutions in one circle, and two circles, so you're looking for 4 solutions.

Comment: Oh ok. I just pretty much hoped for the best and added 180 and took away my value from 360.